# jQuery Remove Dynamically Created Element Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

Here is the code and the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yh3rynab/1/

```
      var i = 1;
       $('body').on('click', '#add_row', function () {
           if (i >4) {
               alert("No more");
               return;
           }
           $('#fg01_container').append('<div class="form-group" id="fg01_0' + i + '"></div>');
           $('#fg01_0' + i).html('<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">CONTENT</div>');
           i++;
       });

       $('body').on('click', '#delete_row', function() {
           if (i > 1) {

               $("#fg01_0" + (i - 1)).remove;
               i--;
           }
       });
```

The code adds fine but it doesn't remove the element that was just created. Please advise!

Comment: `.remove()` instead of `.remove` 

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inexplicable down votes!

Comment: (I think) Most of people like to downvote without explain the reason. Don't worry about it, your question is valid and it is well constructed and formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove is a function. call it like remove()

```
 $("#fg01_0" + (i - 1)).remove();
```

Comment: Holy mother of God... annoying isn't the word to describe my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

remove is method and not property in jquery. You should use `.remove()`  instead of `.remove`

```
 $("#fg01_0" + (i - 1)).remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s0tpgqqo/)**